# Change status of Jira ticket using jira-ruby

Tags: ruby, jira-rest-api

I've tried to get and change status of jira ticket using jira-ruby gem.
I've read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23262558/how-to-change-transitions-to-a-issue-in-ruby-using-jira-ruby-gem) and tried to use this code:

```
require 'jira'
require '../lib/credentials'

options = {
    :username => $user_jira,
    :password => $pwd_jira,
    :site     => "https://example.atlassian.net",
    :context_path => '',
    :auth_type => :basic
}

client = JIRA::Client.new(options)
issue = client.Issue.find("AA-1495")
available_transitions = client.Transition.all(:issue => issue)
available_transitions.each {|ea| puts "#{ea.name} (id #{ea.id})" }
```

And i have empty output. Then I opened transition.rb in jira-ruby gem and added

```
pp path
pp response.body
```

to the "self.all" method.
Then I re-ran my first script and got this output:

```
"https://example.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/16206/transitions"
"{\"expand\":\"transitions\",\"transitions\":[]}"
[Finished in 2.7s]
```

If i try to open link from the first line of output in my browser, i get valid JSON with all available transitions for my jira ticket. So link is OK
As i understand from second line of output, jira response to script is nearly empty.

Somebody had this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you have to get the Jira transition object you need finding by its name:

```
jira_transition = issue.transitions.find{|jt| jt.name = "transition_name_you_need"}
```

then, build a new transition to do and save:

```
transition_to_do = issue.transitions.build
transition_to_do.save!("transition" => {"id" => jira_transition.id})
```

And that's all ;)

Hope it helps

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to lift your content quality up